# What is the maximum weight which adjustable dumbell handles can take?

Tags: dumbbells, weights, plates

Recently I haven't had much time to go to the gym so I decided to buy my own dumbells. I quickly realized adjustable dumbells are more cheaper than normal dumbells. I came across this: http://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/marcy-40-lb-eco-dumbbell-set/6000132108842

Now my question is, is there a maximum weight which each handle can take? As you can see, the link above comes with 4-5lbs, 4-3lbs and 2-4lb handles. I was thinking about putting all the weight on one handle.

By this, I mean:

On one handle, put 2-5lb weights on each side (that makes 20lbs), then put 1-3lb weight on each side (so 26lbs) and with the handle weighing 4 lbs, in total it would be 30lbs (which is a good start off for me).

After, I plan on buying two more weighted plates, each weighing 10lbs. That way, on one dumbell handle, I can have: 2-5lbs and 1-10lb weight on each side, which would make 40lbs of weight on the dumbell handle.

My question is, how do I know if the handle is made to take 40lbs on one handle? Last thing I want is the handle breaking and the weights falling on me.

Comment: Depending on your goals you might want to research 50mm dumbbells. These generally are better quality, but require weight plates with a 50mm hole diameter. I've got some of those and they could easily take 100lbs. As for breaking, I wouldn't really worry. Seeing how small a dumbbell is, and how short the resulting levers are, I don't think you can break your handle. It depends on the product, though and a responsible (read "professional") manufacturer would give you informations on maximum load.

Comment: bear in mind 10lbs plates on a dumbbell handle can noticeably reduce your range of motion compared to regular hex dumbbells in some movements.

Comment: @Affe what do you mean? the handle which I will be holding will be the same length, it's just around the handles where the weights will be added.

Comment: standard 10lbs plates are much larger in circumference than a 40lbs hex dumbell, you cannot hold it as close to your body.  This will either limit range or change the path of movement.  Consider a row, you can't pull it right up into your armpit like with a regular dumbell, the plate will hit your shoulder much sooner.  It's just a thing to consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Most fitness equipment will coming with a safety rating stating clearly and legally the maximum safe weight the product can hold when used in a normal fashion.**

If it doesn't give you a maximum weight, don't buy it as it is probably not very high.